# LEFT JOIN count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count how many transactions have been complete for a course, I am trying to left join the training_transactions with a count of all the rows where the training_transaction_course = course_id and where training_transaction_status = 'completed' Here's the code I have so far:

```
SELECT    training.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT training_transactions.training_transaction_course) AS completed_training_payments
left JOIN users 
ON        training.course_user = users.user_id 
LEFT JOIN training_transactions 
ON        training.course_user = training_transactions.training_transaction_user 
FROM      training 
WHERE     course_id = ? 
AND       training_transactions.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
AND       course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

My tables:

**training transactions**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_transactions` (
  `training_transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_course` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_enabled` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `training_transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**training**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_fitness_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_instructor_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_price` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `course_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `course_max_attendees` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `course_enabled` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I am trying to get the count of completed transactions as a count to deduct from course_max_attendees, and then I can check if there's any places left.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Off topic: Out of interest, what is your reason for prefixing every column? As you can access the columns by `table.column`, I can't help but think that the prefix is redundant.

Comment: @bmsqldev lol, sorry. Updated op

Comment: @JArkinstall TIL, thanks. I thought you had to prefix when joining.

Comment: Your query shouldn't work at all?  is there a typo? your joins are before your FROM statement, unless the Joins are supposed to included in the COUNT aggregatge in which case your need to add some parenthesis and a FROM statement there...

Comment: can u tell exactly what output you need? your questions not clear the things to me. Or you are coming to say your query is not working?

Comment: I think you interpreted my comment the wrong way around. Whilst it's true that your columns are prefixed and there's no point in prefixing in the join (unless the join involves the same table multiple times), my question is about your actual column names. It isn't a criticism, by the way - I have seen it done many times, but I just cannot see how it is useful.

Comment: There's no FROM in your select.

Comment: When outer joining, make sure to have the criteria in the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause. When a `training_transactions` record has to be outer joined (i.e. there is no record so you get a record with all columns set to null), its `training_transaction_status` will be null of course, never 'complete'. So you transform your outer join to an inner join, thus losing trainings that have no entry in `training_transactions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select trainings. So select from `training`. You want to show the transaction count with it, which you can do in a subquery in your select clause:

```
select
  t.*,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from training_transactions tt
    where tt.training_transaction_user = t.course_user
    and tt.training_transaction_status = 'complete'
  ) as completed_training_payments
from training t
where t.course_id = ? 
and t.course_enabled = 'enabled';
```

And here is the same with a join:

```
select
  t.*, coalesce(tt.cnt, 0) as completed_training_payments
from training t
left join
(
  select training_transaction_status, count(*) as cnt
  from training_transactions
  where training_transaction_status = 'complete'
  group by training_transaction_status
) tt on tt.training_transaction_user = t.course_user
where t.course_id = ? 
and t.course_enabled = 'enabled';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to know how many completed transactions have taken place for each course, you can't get the User table involved. You will be aggregating away any user information.

Then, you must start with the course table, which looks like you have named `training`. Now you want to count every completed transaction for each course. A left join works just about perfectly for this:

```
select  t.Name, count( * ) as completed_training_payments
from    training t
left join training_transactions tt
    on  tt.user = t.course_user
    and tt.status = 'complete'
where   t.course_status = 'enabled'
group by t.Name;
```

The problem with this is that it will give a count value of "1" for every course with one completed transaction but also those with no completed transactions at all! So every row with a count of "1" would be suspect. The solution is to count keys, not rows. This is done with the `sum` rather than the `count` function.

```
select  t.Name, sum( case when tt.course_user is null then 0 else 1 end )  as completed_training_payments
from    training t
left join training_transactions tt
    on  tt.user = t.course_user
    and tt.status = 'complete'
where   t.course_status = 'enabled'
group by t.Name;
```

Since `tt.course_user` will only be `null` when there are no completed transactions at all, that course will show a "count" of "0".